# Full viewport carousel - position issue

Tags: css

I've grabbed the full screen carousel code from here:
https://codepen.io/crashy/pen/JoKMgG

What I'd like to do is have it take up the entire viewport on page load, but then the user be able to scroll down the page.

In the CSS I can see it is fixed:

```
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However if I change this to absolute, the images no longer load.  What do I need to change?

Here is the full CSS:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("../img/general/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2;
}
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
    background: url("../img/banner/banner1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
    background: url("../img/banner/banner2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
    background: url("../img/banner/banner3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.carousel {
    z-index: -99;
}
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this changes in your codes,

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
}

.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain myself well enough.  I still want to be able to scroll down the page, but instead of the carousel being permanently in the viewport it should just to attached to the top of the page

Comment: @Lee well no properties are assigned to container, if everything place into it and then it should work.